# Can a read a file from Tomcat Temp folder

Tags: java, tomcat

I am reading byte data and writing a pdf file to my tomcat temp folder

```
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(File.createTempFile("dummy-file", ".pdf"));
```

The file is written successfully.

In a later stage on my application I need to be able to read that file. Can I read any file directly from temp folder? I am not able to

I am using the below path to refer that file while reading.

```
 file:///C:/liferay-developer-studio-1.3.1/Tools/Liferay%20Developer%20Studio/liferay-portal-6.0-ee-sp2/tomcat-6.0.32/temp/dummy-file68824607895269300.pdf  //these numbers are string generated randomly while writing the file.
```

Using this url I see blank result. I assume there is another way to read urls from temp folder? Or is my url wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try the simple case:

```
File pdfFile = File.createTempFile("dummy-file", ".pdf"));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
store(pdfFile.getPath());
```

...

```
File pdfFile = new File(retrieve());
```

If that works, you might try `pdfFile.toURI()`.
Probably something like `file://C:/...` (just 2 or 1 slashes).

Comment: What are store and retrieve methods?

Comment: Pseudo-code, somehow one has to communicate the generated file name.